# Javascript / jQuery check which button is currently playing a song

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to make a song selection list where a user can hit a button to preview a song. I'm struggling with the logic behind setting a buttons innerHTML to read 'Stop preview' when that buttons song is playing and also have the buttons HTML change when a user clicks another button.

Currently my script looks something like:

```
 var playedBy;
var song;
var playing = false;
var audioPlayer = document.getElementById("demo");

function setSong(value, idForPlayed) {
    song = value;
    audioPlayer.src = song;
    audioPlayer.play();
    playedBy = idForPlayed;
    var currentIdPlayingValue = document.getElementById(idForPlayed).value;
    console.log(currentIdPlayingValue);
}


function valueGetter(button) {
    song = button.value;
    button.className += " playing";
    var idForPlayed = button.id;
    var value = song;
    setSong(value, idForPlayed);

}

function doEnd() {
    playing = false;
    console.log('we have an end');
    document.getElementById('demo').pause();
    document.getElementById('demo').currentTime = 0;
}
```

With the value of the buttons being the URL i'm passing the audio object.

Any help is appreciated here, very unsure on the approach i should take.

Thanks all!

Simple example in code pen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXwXYV

Comment: If you could provide a jsfiddle/codepen/etc to help us understand your test case, that'd be great!

Comment: There's no `jQuery` here...

Comment: updated with a code pen :) Also yes Melancia i am aware but the logic behind it is the issue I am having not the programming language used ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could toggle the innerHtml and all of the other buttons html on click.

Something like

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  //Add or remove a class for the clicked button to determine if it's playing.
  $(this).toggleClass('playing');

  if($(this).hasClass('playing')){
    //Set all buttons back to play
    //And probably call some sort of Stop Playing function
    $('.btn').html('Play').removeClass('playing');

    $(this).html('Stop Playing').addClass('playing');
  }else{
    $('.btn').html('Play').removeClass('playing');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey RickT thank you for your comment, the issue with that is that all buttons will get the html of Play, right? When I would only want the one that is playing to read Play

Comment: Well, substitute 'Play' for whatever you want as placeholder, when it's not playing.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for your help :D